# Vuetify Problem: How to change inner elements width of a banner?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to insert search form in banner, based on vuetify.

```
<v-banner app v-model="show" two-line transition="slide-y-transition">
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field label="textfield" />
    <v-select :items="select_1" label="select 1" />
    <v-select :items="select_2" label="select 2" />
  </v-form>
</v-banner>
```

[result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJhSa.png)

I did it, but it doesn't looks good. I expect textfield and select have a full width in banner, but it doesn't.

So, I filled dummy texts in banner. Then, it was worked.

```
<v-banner app v-model="show" two-line transition="slide-y-transition">
  dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field label="textfield" />
    <v-select :items="select_1" label="select 1" />
    <v-select :items="select_2" label="select 2" />
  </v-form>
</v-banner>
```

[result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLcEJ.png)

---

How can I change inner elements width of banner without dummy text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between v-banner and v-form there is another element added by vuetify - it is v-banner__text

Add this your  tag to give it 100% width:

```
<style scoped>
  .v-banner__text {
    width: 100%
  }
</style>
```